# Android Studio Windows script : gradlew command not found

Tags: android, windows, gradle, gradlew

I want to run below git hook task before every commit on Android Studio on Windows 10 machine

```
#!/bin/bash
git stash -q --keep-index
echo "Running git pre-commit hook"
gradlew ktlintCheck
RESULT=$?
git stash pop -q
# return 1 exit code if running checks fails
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

On windows machine it gives error as "gradlew command not found", although I am able to run gradlew commands using cmd.
Below is the task for running git-hook:

```
task installGitHook(type: Copy) {
    from new File(rootProject.rootDir, 'pre-commit')
    into { new File(rootProject.rootDir, '.git/hooks') }
    fileMode 0777
}
tasks.getByPath(':app:preBuild').dependsOn installGitHook
```

Comment: Make sure that the `.git` folder and `gradlew` are in the same parent folder. Also change the command into your script from `gradlew ktlintCheck` to `./gradlew ktlintCheck`. Although I am not sure if this is a fix it is worth a try!